# Which generative methods are better for generating graphs, while preserving node and edge labels?

Tags: machine-learning, generative-adversarial-networks, generative-model, geometric-deep-learning

I started to dig into the topic of graph generation and I have a question - which out of generative methods (autoregressive, variational autoencoders, GANs, any other?) are better for generating graphs while preserving both node and edge labels? (in other words, I want to generate graphs with node and edge labels, similar to what I have in my dataset)

I checked over some papers, but I didn't find exact clues about how to choose the method for graph generation. If anybody is more familiar with the topic, I'll appreciate any link to papers or any advice/recommendations.